# Python get the text inside of "div" tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i am trying to make a requests and get the all strings which are inside of div tag etc:

```
            <div class='td allow_tip  ' ><h3><a href='/exploit/description/25950'>WordPress Userpro Remote File Upload Exploit</a></h3>
```

How to do it with python? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already used `requests` to get the `html_source` and stored it in variable `s`, you can use the following code to extract the text of the desired tags (`a tags` in the example):

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = "<div class='td allow_tip  ' ><h3><a href='/exploit/description/25950'>WordPress Userpro Remote File Upload Exploit</a></h3>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
for a in a_tags:
    print(a.text)
```

**Output:**

```
'WordPress Userpro Remote File Upload Exploit'
```